# Is there an official approach for implementing a plugin system in an R package?

Tags: r, plugins

Python has a few officially recognized approaches for developing a plugin system for your python module, which are described in the [Python documentation for creating and discovering plugins](https://packaging.python.org/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/).

For example, one way is to use package metadata to declare a plugin package as a plugin; then in the host package, you search through all installed python packages for those that have declared themselves as a plugin in the way you expect.

I suppose you could do something similar with package names; for example, say I have package `MyRPackage` and I want to develop a plugin system. I could use `installed.packages` to search for any package named `MyRPackage_plugin_xyz`, where xyz is the name of the plugin, and then use functions of a specified name in those packages to execute at certain point in `MyRPackage`.

So, it can be done -- my question is, does R provide specific official way to do this? Or, are there any packages that provide such capability?

Comment: Questions asking for opinion based answers are normally closed. Please rephrase before that occurs.  Also some small example code to illustrate what this is all about should be included.

Comment: I was not intending to ask for opinions, really. I am wondering if there's any way to do this, or an officially approved approach. It appears there may not be.

Comment: I think the closest system available and recognised is to use the SUGGESTS field in the package description for packages, that are not required but can be used. Then you can check with ```requireNamespace(x, quietly = TRUE))``` before using such a function in the main package. The plugin package would then use the ENHANCES statement in the Description. See also http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html for an excellent overview